# If $e$ is powered to n-th multiplier of $2\pi$ should the real part of the multiplied by this multiplier or it must be left as it is?

Tags: complex-analysis

Hopefully the title is not too confusing, but imagine there is an expression $e^{2+i(\ln(3)-10\pi k)}$

I am not sure does the $-10\pi k$ automatically reduces as a n-th multiply of $2\pi$ or is there any extra steps to be made?

For example, I have an expression: $$e^{3i(ln(4) + i(-\frac{\pi}{2}+4\pi k)) } = e^{\frac{3\pi}{2}-12\pi k}(\cos(3ln(4))+i\sin(3\ln(4))), \ \ k \in Z$$
Is this correct?

Comment: So is the question about simplifying the expression, or what are you trying to do? Indeed 
$$
e^{i 2\pi} = 1
$$

Comment: @MattiP. So in this case it would be solved as: $e^{2+i(ln(3)-10\pi k)} = e^2(cos(ln(3))+isin(ln(3))$?

Comment: @Fakemistake I can, but the question is whether the $10 \pi k $ cancels out as a multiply of $2\pi k$ or no?

Comment: If $k$ is an integer, you can "disregard" that term.

Comment: @Deepak Thank you, the answer that I was looking for. :D

Comment: @Deepak The same goes if it' s a real part, right? If $e^{\frac{\pi}{2}-10\pi} = e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$?

Comment: @user Definitely not. It only works with the exponent that's purely imaginary (you must have the $i$) and a multiple of $2\pi$ because $e^{2\pi i} = 1$ so $e^{2k\pi i} = (e^{2\pi i})^k = 1^k =1$ for integer $k$ . It does not work for real exponents.

Comment: @Deepak I wrote an example and want to make sure that it's correct now.

Comment: @user Looks wrong. But balance your brackets first because your expression is ambiguous. 3 left (open) but only 2 right (close) brackets in the first line. Then I can tell what expression you intended.

Comment: @Deepak I edited my post.

Comment: @user Please fix brackets in this: $e^{3i(ln(4) + i(-\frac{\pi}{2}+4\pi k) } $ Do you want the $3i$ to distributively multiply over both the $\ln 4$ and the other term (also with $i$ in it)?

Comment: Deepak Yes, I edited my post, so hopefully it's clear now.

Comment: @user I've written a (probably overlong) answer just to clarify your doubts. See if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address the example:

$$e^{3i(\ln(4) + i(-\frac{\pi}{2}+4\pi k))}$$

First work on the exponent. This is simple algebra, distribution. Remember $i\cdot i = -1$.

$$e^{{i(3\ln 4)} \ - \ 3(-\frac{\pi}{2}+4k\pi)}$$

Note the exponent is a complex number. Using the rules of exponentiation, separate the expression so the real and imaginary parts are apart:

$$e^{-3(-\frac{\pi}{2}+4k\pi)}e^{i(3\ln 4)}$$

You can now write down your final answer using Euler's formula.

$$e^{-3(-\frac{\pi}{2}+4k\pi)}(\cos(3\ln 4) + i\sin (3\ln 4))$$

Note that the $\displaystyle (\cos(3\ln 4) + i\sin (3\ln 4))$ part is a complex number with magnitude one.

And note that you're multiplying that by a purely real number $\displaystyle e^{-3(-\frac{\pi}{2}+4k\pi)}$. So the overall magnitude of the final complex number will be equal to $\displaystyle e^{-3(-\frac{\pi}{2}+4k\pi)}$. The argument of the final complex number is $\displaystyle 3\ln 4$ in radian measure.

You can of course rewrite the first part as $\displaystyle e^{\frac{3\pi}{2}-12k\pi}$ or even as $\displaystyle e^{\frac{3\pi}2(1-8k)}$. Nothing special, just basic algebra in real numbers.

As for the very first example you mentioned, $\displaystyle e^{2+i(\ln(3)-10\pi k)}$, observe that the exponent is already neatly separated into real and imaginary parts. If you apply the same methods as above, you can see that it's equal to $\displaystyle e^2e^{i(\ln 3-10\pi k)} = e^2(\cos(\ln 3-10\pi k) + i\sin(\ln 3-10\pi k))$.

Now note that because of the periodicity ($2\pi$) of the trigonometric functions (sine and cosine), you can rewrite that as $\displaystyle e^2(\cos(\ln 3)+ i\sin(\ln 3))$.

The reason for this is exactly why you can write $\cos(\theta + 2\pi) = \cos(\theta + 4\pi) = \cos(\theta - 10\pi)=\cos\theta$ and so forth. Nothing mysterious in it.

Complex numbers in exponential form are intimately related to trigonometric functions. This is exemplified in identities like $e^{i\pi} = \cos \pi + i\sin \pi = -1$ and $e^{i2\pi} = \cos 2\pi + i\sin 2\pi = 1$. And of course the general Euler's formula, which is $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$. It is the periodicity of the trigonometric functions that allows you to write things like $e^{i(\theta + 2k\pi)} = \cos (\theta + 2k\pi) + i\sin (\theta + 2k\pi) = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$. But don't ever make the mistake of carrying that thinking over to the real expressions that don't involve trigonometric functions.